# GetElementById in other website

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I want replace my current page by a page with the URL:

My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="Script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JS (Script.js) :

```
window.onload = function displayH1(){
    document.location = "http://www.website.com";
    var c = document.getElementsById("email");
    c.style.display = 'none';
    alert(c);
}
```

In finally, I want get elements of web site and change value of this element.
But I have just the URL.

Comment: You can't do that. You'd need to create a browser extension

Comment: You could use an iframe with the website's source... but you can't change other website data like that, you could view it in the iframe

Comment: Use iframe but if iframe's source is an external domain, browsers will hide the iframe contents (Same Origin Policy). A workaround is saving the external contents with PHP and access-it with ajax request to your php script

Comment: I don't iframe but I will try. The problem with extension is that I must install it in other browsers... I want the user don't activate extension when he want use application...